# How do I Add an Event Handler To the RowUpdated event in a table adapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a tableadapter and I want to do something when the RowUpdated event is fired. I can't figure out where to put the code to add the handler to the event.

```
public partial class MyTableAdapter
{
  void OnRowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
}
```

How do I get the code below to run when the TableAdapter is created?

```
Adapter.RowUpdated += 
                   new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);
```

Comment: If you have the chance to put it right after the `Adapter`'s creation, I would put it there If you have an `InitializeComponent` method that does the initialization for you in the container class'es constructor put the code right after the call of `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: I've put a bounty on this question because it's a problem I have had regularly since the days of .net 1.1 and I feel there must be a better solution to this than hacking the table adapter after I instantiate it.

Comment: the solutions provided in the answeres are pragmatically good and technically sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this in 2 stages.

a. add partial class and extend table adapter

b. call a method in the beginning before using this adapter (say in main form after you create instance of it).

The code below is to resolve my particular issue with SQL CE to be able to update IDs on the table. However you can use the extended method to wrap the RowUpdated event and expose it to other classes (ie MyRowUpdated)

The extension

```
public partial class ScannedItemsTableAdapter
{
    public void InitEvents()
    {
        this._adapter.RowUpdated += _adapter_RowUpdated;
    }

    void _adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, SqlCeRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue && 
            e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
        {
            var pk = e.Row.Table.PrimaryKey;
            pk[0].ReadOnly = false;

            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", 
               e.Command.Connection, e.Command.Transaction);

            object id = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            e.Row[pk[0]] = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            e.Row.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The call in the main form:

```
        tableAdapter = new ScannedItemsTableAdapter();
        tableAdapter.Fill(ds.ScannedItems);
        tableAdapter.InitEvents();
```

Comment: This is how I have solved the problem, however I was looking for a way to wire up the event in the table adapter class when the table adapter is created.

Comment: Thanks. This is how I ended up as well. For future readers, be sure you call `InitEvents()` AFTER your adapter object has been initialized and not in your form's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

it has been a while since i last used this stuff, but if i remember correctly you should be able to override `EndInit()` in your partial class and add init code like adding your event handler there ...

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible alternative.

Whilst one can subscribe to the tableadapters underlying adapter in the tableadapter partial class I find you cannot easily initialise it without having to remember to call an initialisation of your own.

However I found that I can subscribe to a tableadapters.adapter.rowupdated event directly from within code using the tableadpater as below

```
AddHandler Me.TA_Case_Transactions.Adapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf Transaction_Row_Written

  Private Sub Transaction_Row_Written(p_Sender As Object, p_E As SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
        beep
    End Sub
```

"The beep is so I can add a breakpoint for testing"

Since I would have to subscribe to the event anyway I think this is more intuitive and doesnt require any "remembering"

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **None of the steps suggested below are useful, apparently.** I'm keeping this answer here purely so that anyone else trying to answer it doesn't come up with the same suggestions.

---

Are you creating the `TableAdapter` in the designer? If so, can you not just click on the Events part of the properties page, and type "OnRowUpdated" into the `RowUpdated` entry?

If you're creating the adapter explicitly in your code, just add the call yourself.

Alternatively, does your partial class have a constructor which is being called? Again, if so, you can add the call there.

EDIT: Okay, so presumably this is being used in a particular page or form - can you add it after the `InitializeComponent` method of that page/form?

Comment: I am using the designer to create a typed dataset with a data table and table adapter. There is no events part of the properties page that I can see. 

As the designer has created a constructor I can't add to it in the partial class.

Comment: @Simon: I was referring to the designer where you're *using* the adapter - i.e. the form/whatever where you're including it. Not the data set designer.

Comment: I could make the OnRowUpdated handler public and use this code on the form:
    MyTableAdapter myAdapter = new MyTableAdapter();
    myAdapter.Adapter.RowUpdated += new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler(myAdapter.OnRowUpdated);

However I would prefer to do this in the adapter's partial class so that the users of the dataset don't have to remember to add this code every time they create an instance of the adapter.

Comment: Jon, there is no 'events' pane on the Form either.

Comment: Okay, it looks like this answer isn't terribly useful then... will edit to say so, but leave it up as a list of things we've tried :)

Answer (score 0):

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=14625 if you look at this video you can see, that you just double click on something in the dataset designer and the event gets generated and wired up for you....but this works only for VB programmers :)) sux

Comment: to be more specific @5:00 minute Beth double clicks the datatable and gets xxRowChanging event

Answer (score 0):

Override endinitin your C# class and fire event handler from there

```
    public override void EndInit()
    {
        base.EndInit();
        Adapter.RowUpdated += 
                   new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);

    }

    void OnRowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Hope that helps................

Comment: The TableAdapter class does not let you override EndInit (no suitable method found to override). The DataTable partial class does allow you to override EndInit however I can't see how to access the related TableAdapter from the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.

SqlDataAdapter custAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers", connection);

// Add handlers.

custAdapter.RowUpdating += new SqlRowUpdatingEventHandler(OnRowUpdating);
custAdapter.RowUpdated += new SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);

// Set DataAdapter command properties, fill DataSet, modify DataSet.


custAdapter.Update(custDS, "Customers");

// Remove handlers.

custAdapter.RowUpdating -= new SqlRowUpdatingEventHandler(OnRowUpdating);
custAdapter.RowUpdated -= new SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);

protected static void OnRowUpdating(
  object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.StatementType == StatementType.Delete)
  {
    System.IO.TextWriter tw = System.IO.File.AppendText("Deletes.log");
    tw.WriteLine(
      "{0}: Customer {1} Deleted.", DateTime.Now, 
       args.Row["CustomerID", DataRowVersion.Original]);
    tw.Close();
  }
}

protected static void OnRowUpdated(
  object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)
  {
    args.Row.RowError = args.Errors.Message;

    args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Answers are better when they're accompanied with some *explanation*, rather than simply a wall of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it, using the Designer. Right-click on the dataset (the .xsd file) and select View Code. Just like with a form, it's not going to open the designer code. It's going to open your code. Here's your code:

```
namespace TimeTrack.TimeTrackDataSetTableAdapters
{
    public partial class TimeSlipsTableAdapter
    {
        public void CustomSetup()
        {
            Adapter.RowUpdated += Adapter_RowUpdated;
        }

        private void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // whatever you want to do when RowUpdated fires
        }
    }
}
```

In your form, don't forget to

```
    public TimeEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timeSlipsTableAdapter.CustomSetup();
```