# Where can I add an event handler To the RowUpdated event for a table adapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have strongly typed dataset and Data Access Layer top of it.

I am extending partial class of tableadpater.

```
public partial class InvoiceTableAdapter 
{

    public void OnRowUpdated(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am here");
    }

}
```

Question: Where can i add event handler for this?

Comment: I have posted a possible answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243881/how-do-i-add-an-event-handler-to-the-rowupdated-event-in-a-table-adapter/35650508#35650508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use VB.NET, you can doubleclick somewhere and the event-code is generated. In C# you need to override EndInit() and code it yourself.

Here's [something on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1120xds5%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Henk,
It work as i am looking for. appreciate your help.